# JQuery validation - is .validate() needed when using .valid()?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I recently realized that one of my pages does not contain:  $("#form1").validate(); call, however the page does a jquery validation on the 'required' fields.

I do have code at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var originalDoPostBack = __doPostBack;
    __doPostBack = function(sender, args) {
        if ($("#form1").valid() === true) {
            originalDoPostBack(sender, args);
        }
    };
</script>
```

My testing and viewing the source seems that that I do not need the **$("#form1").validate()** if I have **$("#form1").valid()**.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.validate()` is used to set up the form and it's fields for validation. For example, to set the rules, such as `required` and `email`, and to define the messages to be displayed on errors. It also attaches to the `submit` event of your form so that it automatically calls `$("form").valid()` on form submit.

Example:

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: { 
        Username: { required: true, email: true },
        Password: { required: true }
    },
    messages: { 
        Username: {
            required: "Please enter your username",
            email: "Please enter a valid username"
        },
        Password: "Please enter your password"
    }
});

<form>
    <input type="text" id="Username" name="Username" />
    <input type="text" id="Password" name="Password" />
</form>
```

Alternatively you can use classes for the rules, and the `title` attribute on the fields for the error messages. Using this method you will need to manually call `$("form").valid()` when the form is submit.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    return $(this).valid();
});

<form>
    <input type="text" id="Username" name="Username" class="required email" title="Please enter your username" />
    <input type="text" id="Password" name="Password" class="required" title="Please enter your password" />
</form>
```

It's worth noting that the first method gives you far more control over the appearance and settings of the form, and is also a better separation of concerns IMO. The only benefit of the latter is it's brevity.